# Why is my website not loading on first load in react.js? If I press the reload button ,the site loads

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser-cache

My website doesn't load on localhost and my domain when first load. But the page works if I refresh the page. What could be the reason for this? Beacuse I'm not making any changes, only reaload page and page is load. And how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Does the HTML show up at all? In source (developer console). Also what kind of response is the server providing you in network, also in developer console.

Comment: no, only white screen.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: That's no exactly what I am asking. In developer console, you will have a source tab and a network tab. Check network tab for the localhost call and see what the response code was. In source there's a localhost as well see if it outputted any items, this will answer a lot.